# Prime Ideals in Polynomial Quotient Ring

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, irreducible-polynomials

Let $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ be the ring of polynomials in one variable over $\mathbb{Z}$.

I want to consider the quotient ring $R=\mathbb{Z}[x]/(2x)$. I would like to know how to find the prime ideals of $R$.

I am not sure how to tackle this question. I know about the classification of prime ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. However, I don't know how the ring $R$ looks like.

Does this even matter? Could we use the correspondence between prime ideals of the quotient ring $R$ and prime ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ containing $(2x)$?

Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: Indeed, you can use the correspondence between prime ideals of the quotient ring $R$ and the prime ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ containing $(2x)$. What can you say about the ideals containing $(2x)$, how many are there?

Comment: What are the prime ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ containing $(2x)$?

Comment: I think the elements of $(2x)$ are those polynomials whose constant term is zero and where all the other coefficients are even. So, I would say that the ideal $(2)$ should be one example of a candidate. Is this the way to think?